# How to separate two if statements in my code?

Tags: c

I wrote the code below and I have a problem I don't know how to separate the first if and the second if.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{

    printf("welcome user\n");

    printf("please answer this following questions\n");
    printf("what is your age");

    int age;

    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("your age is %d\n", age);

    int main();
    {
        int age = 30;
        if (age < 30);

        printf("you are yong i like that\n ");
        int main();
        if (age > 30);
        printf("you are to old\n ");
        printf("its ok you still human\n");
        printf("XD\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have so many `int main()`s??? There should only be one :O

Comment: Your code has several things that don't make sense.

Comment: `if` only applies to the following expression, putting a `;` on the end of the `if` means it applies to nothing

Comment: The two `age` variables are different instances. Because the second one is in a `{` code block `}` it shadows the first one. The `int main();` (twice) are unnecessary declarations.

Comment: The semicolon on this line ends the if () making it pointless: `if (age < 30);` basically its if age is less than 30 do nothing.

Comment: I only now noticed the **third** `int main()`.  I suspect OP may not be at a stage where they can explain what each line of code here is doing.

Comment: May I kindly recommend taking a basic C tutorial? There are many issues in this code which that might help to clarify for you.

Comment: Best C question I've ever seen. I'm glad people here have tried to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want your code to be revised to somewhere along the lines of this:

Remove these extra unnecessary main() and have if and else if block or just else block contained in braces. Also, although not required for correct code execution, indent for better readability. And finally delete the `int age = 30;` line.

```
int main()
{

    printf("welcome user\n");

    printf("please answer this following questions\n");
    printf("what is your age");

    int age;

    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("your age is %d\n", age);

    if (age < 30) // if more than one line, must contain if block within braces
        printf("you are yong i like that\n ");
  
    else if (age > 30) {
        printf("you are to old\n ");
        printf("its ok you still human\n");
        printf("XD\n");
    }
}
```